# check list with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I have problem when i get the list from server i want to check it, if it's any object there or not.
if there are object , appears in my layout text : there is no object after few seconds it's disappears
 and show my list.

i want just if there is object will appear in my layout directly.
               private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask> {

```
    @Override
    protected List<branch> doInBackground(String... params) {

        manager = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        manager.checkLogin();
        HashMap<String, String> user = manager.getUserID();
        String uid = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_uid);
       // Intent intent= getActivity().getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
        //String type18 = intent.getStringExtra("key28");
        String strUrl = 

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("markers");

            ////////////////////////////////////////
            List<branch> bList = new ArrayList<>();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                /////////market object
                market mr = new market(Integer.valueOf(finalObject.getString("id")), finalObject.getString("mName")
                        , finalObject.getString("pic"));

                /////////location object
                location lo = new location(Float.valueOf(finalObject.getString("lat")), Float.valueOf(finalObject.getString("lng"))
                        , finalObject.getString("area"), finalObject.getString("city"));


                /////////(branch object) inside it (market object)
                branch it = new branch(Integer.valueOf(finalObject.getString("bid")), Integer.valueOf(finalObject.getString("phone"))
                        , finalObject.getString("ser"), Integer.valueOf(finalObject.getString("dis")), Integer.valueOf(finalObject.getString("brNo"))
                        , Float.valueOf(finalObject.getString("rating")), mr, lo,true);

                /*//////////add marker
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(finalObject.getString("lat")), Double.valueOf(finalObject.getString("lng")));
                addMarker(latlng, Integer.valueOf(finalObject.getString("bid")));*/

                // adding the branch object in the list
                bList.add(it);
            }
            return bList;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;

    }
```

here the postExcute

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<branch> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result != null) {

            final itemAdapter adapter = new itemAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_favmarkets, result);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }

}
```

this is my layout xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
tools:context="com.gmplatform.gmp.favouriteitem">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView28"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:text="There is no Markets in your Favourite List.."
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/l20"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="400dp" />
```

Comment: Is the text that indicates "there is no object" being set to visible before the async task is executed? Is it set in the xml? Could you post your xml layout?

Comment: @ahasbini i post my xml , check it please

Answer (score 0):

Suggested changes which will at first show nothing when the request is executed. Once completed, if the list is empty it'll show "There is no Markets in your Favourite List..", otherwise the list will show.

Part Layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout28">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView28"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:text="There is no Markets in your Favourite List.."
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Initialize `linearLayout28`:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout28 = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout28);
```

And changes for the AsyncTask:

```
private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<branch>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        linearLayout28.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<branch> doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Keep as your code
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<branch> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result != null && result.size() != 0) {
            final itemAdapter adapter = new itemAdapter(
                getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.row_favmarkets, result);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            linearLayout28.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linearLayout28.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically on the solution but you should not update the user interface from your AsyncTask. Create an interface and implement it on the Activity. Let the activity to update the data on the UI when data is ready or show a message error.

As an example, define the interface in your AsyncTask like:

```
private TaskCallback listener = null;

public interface TaskCallback {
    void OnTaskCompleted ();
}

public void setListener (TaskCallback listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

When your task was completed:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute (Void v) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.OnTaskCompleted ();
    }
}
```

You can add parameters to your callback base on your needs.

At your Activity level:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements YourTask.TaskCallback {

//  When you execute your task add the reference to the listener
YourTask task = new YourTask (YourActivity.this);
        task.setListener (YourActivity.this);
        task.execute ();


@Override
public void OnTaskCompleted () {
    //  Update your screen or show an error message
}

}
```